# Ampersand or no ampersand before string variable name in scanf() and printf()?

Tags: c, string, printf, scanf

The compiler I'm using is Dev C++ 5.11. TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32-bit Debug. C99 mode.

### 1.

```
 char str1[100], str2[100];
 scanf("%s %s", &str1, &str2);
 printf("%s %s", &str1, &str2);
```

### 2.

```
 char str1[100], str2[100];
 scanf("%s %s", &str1, &str2);
 printf("%s %s", str1, str2);
```

### 3.

```
 char str1[100], str2[100];
 scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
 printf("%s %s", str1, str2);
```

Every code works. Why? I'm very confused.

Comment: If you want a sample that potentially exhibits different behaviours, compare `scanf("%s %s", &str1 + 1, &str2 + 1)` (which definitely has undefined behaviour) with `scanf("%s %s", str1 + 1, str2 + 1)` (which only has undefined behaviour if the user enters too much data).     I'll leave it as an exercise for you to work out why the potential difference is more pronounced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `str1` gives a char pointer `char*` to the first element, which will be allocated at the first address in the array.
- `&str1` gives an *array pointer* to the array as whole, of type `char(*)[100]`.
- The address of the array is always the same as the address of the first element.
- By using the `%s` format specifier you tell printf to treat the passed pointer as a `char*`. So no matter which pointer type you pass, it will get converted to this type.
- As it happens, this particular pointer conversion from `char(*)[100]` to `char*` has to yield the very same address, so the code works no matter which pointer type you use.

Comment: Although everything you say is true, it is probably worth mentioning that the OP's case 3 is advisable since the type passed is actually what the functions expect (i.e. pass a `char *` rather than `char(*)[100]` for the argument corresponding to a `%s` format).

Comment: @Peter Indeed. Good compilers might parse the printf format string and then whine accordingly if the passed type doesn't correspond to the expected type.

Comment: A certain number of programmers would whine too, with some justification.    ;)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you need to remember is that arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element. That is, in your example `str1` and `&str1[0]` are equal.

The second thing to remember is that a pointer to an array, and a pointer to its first element will point to the same location, but they are semantically different since they are different types. Again taking your array `str1` as example: When you do `&str1` you get something of type `char (*)[100]`, while plain `str1` (or its equivalent `&str[0]`) you get something of type `char *`. Those are very different types.

Last thing you need to remember is that both `scanf` and `printf` when reading/printing strings take a pointer to a `char` (i.e. `char *`). See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [this `printf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) references for details.

All that means is that only alternative 3 in your question is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

In C, any expression of array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element unless it has reference operator.

```
scanf("%s %s", &str1, &str2);
```

is

```
scanf("%s %s", &str1[100], &str2[100]);
```

and the address of the array is always the same as the address of the first element.

Comment: No it is not `implicitly converted` to  &str[0] as `&str[]` and `&str[0]` have completely  different types, but point to the the same object

Answer (score 0):

Because it string is an array of the char. So address of the array is the address oh it's first element.

They just have different types.